# Counting beginning whitespaces

Tags: php, regex

I want to count (within a single regular expression) all spaces at the beginning of a string.

My ideas:

```
$identSize = preg_match_all("/^( )[^ ]/", $line, $matches);
```

For example:

```
$example1 = " Foo"; // should return 1
$example2 = "  Bar"; // should return 2
$example3 = "   Foo bar"; // should return 3, not 4!
```

Any tips, how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$identSize = strlen($line)-strlen(ltrim($line));
```

Or, if you want regular expression,

```
preg_match('/^(\s+)/',$line,$matches);
$identSize = strlen($matches[1]);
```

Comment: First one is smart. I can imagine that it's faster than the preg_match version.

Comment: +1, but your first version takes into account only spaces, you might wanna include other whitespace characters too.

Comment: @codaddict Though OPs question was to count spaces, therefor if there is any remarks to be made it's regarding the specified regular expression.

Comment: @codaddict, as I know, not only spaces - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php (see "Return Values")

Comment: @refp: The question title says whitespace but the regex in question counts only space. If OP want only space then Timur 2nd solution needs to be changed to include only space.

Comment: @codaddict Ah yeah, that's true.. I was a bit quick to judge there, thanks.

Comment: +1, first method is great but won't work if there are trailing white spaces as well. I removed them before using it.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using a regular expression (or any other hack) you should use `strspn`, which is defined to handle these kinds of problems.

```
$a = array (" Foo", "  Bar", "   Foo Bar");

foreach ($a as $s1)
  echo strspn ($s1, ' ') . " <- '$s1'\n";
```

output

```
1 <- ' Foo'
2 <- '  Bar'
3 <- '   Foo Bar'
```

If OP wants to count more than just spaces (ie. other white characters) the 2nd argument to `strspn` should be `" \t\r\n\0\x0B"` (taken from what `trim` defines as white characters).

Documentation [PHP: strspn - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a preg_match for consecutive whitespace (So that it matched string returns "   ")at the beginning of the string.

Then you could use strlen on the match to return the number of whitepace chars.